# Guidance on app submitted to AppSource that targets Enterprise B2B Customers

Tags: office-store

We recently submitted our Add-in for approval to be available on AppSource/Office Store and failed approval. Some of the feedback and policies make sense and we have addressed those items. However, there are a few policies that I'm not sure how to address and looking for guidance.

1. Policy 7.1 & 7.16 are about the supportURL not being publicly available and requiring Sign-in. Our add-in is not a general user add-in but targeted to Enterprise Customers of our Platform. They are provided a login for our support site so is this not sufficient? Do we really need a public url for an add-in targeted to Enterprise Customers?

As I was writing this I found the following link and wanted to make sure this was still valid and the same guidance for my scenario: [App Submission - Help/Support Link Requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331266/app-submission-help-support-link-requirement)

2. Policy 11.3 are about the Start-up experience needs to engage the user and show value proposition. Our users are Enterprise Users and have signed up for platform in which we will already guide them to use the Excel Add-in. Since they already know the value proposition from our sales team is there a way that this can be handled in our scenario without needing an explicit startup video or wizard walk through of app features?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a customer support issue.

Comment: This is the preferred method for MS to provide standard answers that multiple users can benefit from and the above questions are similar questions other developers of office add-ins will run into when submitting their add-ins to the office store.

Comment: I bet it is, but this isn't a MS service and they can't decide what's on-topic here and what's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this must be a public URL. The support link in your Seller Dashboard listing appears on the AppSource website so must be publicly available. It can be a link to your main website / or a contact page on your main website.
2. Have you seen the documentation on submitting [Enterprise](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/office-store-validation-policy-changes-to-support-apps-and-add-ins-that-target-larger-organizations-and-enterprises/) add-ins? This outlines which policies are not applicable when submitting an add-in which targets larger organizations and enterprises. It also explains how to declare, via test notes, that you are submitting an Enterprise add-in.